# Compiling C and sqlite3

Tags: c, windows, gcc, sqlite

I'm having some trouble incorporating sqlite3 into a program I'm writing. I've been scouring the internet over the past few days attempting to find a solution. I'm using the MinGW compiler and have already tried:

- Ensuring the C:\MinGW\bin directory is included in both the user and system environment Path variables with no spaces and separated with a semi-colon
- Using the command prompt and entering "C:\MinGW\bin\gcc shell.c sqlite3.c -lpthread -ldl" in the same directory of all related files which returns the result "c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -ldl
  collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status"
- Fresh install of MinGW and eclipse

If it helps this is the code I'm testing this with, I can't get the includes to show up as code but they are all in carets in order, iostream, stdio.h, and sqlite3.h
It returns the error "fatal error: sqlite3.h: No such file or directory". I have all of the include files in the same directory as the .cpp source as well.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    sqlite3 *db;
    char *zErrMsg = 0;
    int rc;
    rc = sqlite3_open("text.db", &db);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fiddling around a bit I realized all I had to do was #include "sqlite3.h" with the sqlite.h file in the source file directory and include the sqlite3.c file in the project tree. I'm using DevC++ and I went to project > add to project and select the sqlite3.c file. Then project > project options > files and select sqlite3.c then uncheck "compile file as C++".

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "sqlite3.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    sqlite3 *db;
    char *zErrMsg = 0;
    int rc;
    rc = sqlite3_open("text.db", &db);
    return 0;
}
```

Compile and test result:

```
w00343520@wuhy1w001184171 MINGW64 /d/Download/sqlite-amalgamation-3190200/sqlite-amalgamation-3190200
$ mingw32-gcc -o test main.c sqlite3.c -I./

w00343520@wuhy1w001184171 MINGW64 /d/Download/sqlite-amalgamation-3190200/sqlite-amalgamation-3190200
$ ll
total 8485
-rw-r--r-- 1 w00343520 1049089     192 六月  8 10:38 main.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 w00343520 1049089  236938 五月 26 00:15 shell.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 w00343520 1049089 7130198 五月 26 00:15 sqlite3.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 w00343520 1049089  498184 五月 26 00:15 sqlite3.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 w00343520 1049089   30199 五月 26 00:15 sqlite3ext.h
-rwxr-xr-x 1 w00343520 1049089  785640 六月  8 10:38 test.exe*

w00343520@wuhy1w001184171 MINGW64 /d/Download/sqlite-amalgamation-3190200/sqlite-amalgamation-3190200
$ ./test.exe

w00343520@wuhy1w001184171 MINGW64 /d/Download/sqlite-amalgamation-3190200/sqlite-amalgamation-3190200
$ ll
total 8485
-rw-r--r-- 1 w00343520 1049089     192 六月  8 10:38 main.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 w00343520 1049089  236938 五月 26 00:15 shell.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 w00343520 1049089 7130198 五月 26 00:15 sqlite3.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 w00343520 1049089  498184 五月 26 00:15 sqlite3.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 w00343520 1049089   30199 五月 26 00:15 sqlite3ext.h
-rwxr-xr-x 1 w00343520 1049089  785640 六月  8 10:38 test.exe*
-rw-r--r-- 1 w00343520 1049089       0 六月  8 10:41 text.db

w00343520@wuhy1w001184171 MINGW64 /d/Download/sqlite-amalgamation-3190200/sqlite-amalgamation-3190200
$
```

The test result for shell.c:

```
w00343520@wuhy1w001184171 MINGW64 /d/Download/sqlite-amalgamation-3190200/sqlite-amalgamation-3190200
$ mingw32-gcc -o sqlite shell.c sqlite3.c -I./

w00343520@wuhy1w001184171 MINGW64 /d/Download/sqlite-amalgamation-3190200/sqlite-amalgamation-3190200
$ ./sqlite.exe



w00343520@wuhy1w001184171 MINGW64 /d/Download/sqlite-amalgamation-3190200/sqlite-amalgamation-3190200
$ ./sqlite.exe --help
Usage: D:\Download\sqlite-amalgamation-3190200\sqlite-amalgamation-3190200\sqlite.exe [OPTIONS] FILENAME [SQL]
FILENAME is the name of an SQLite database. A new database is created
if the file does not previously exist.
OPTIONS include:
   -ascii               set output mode to 'ascii'
   -bail                stop after hitting an error
   -batch               force batch I/O
   -column              set output mode to 'column'
   -cmd COMMAND         run "COMMAND" before reading stdin
   -csv                 set output mode to 'csv'
   -echo                print commands before execution
   -init FILENAME       read/process named file
   -[no]header          turn headers on or off
   -help                show this message
   -html                set output mode to HTML
   -interactive         force interactive I/O
   -line                set output mode to 'line'
   -list                set output mode to 'list'
   -lookaside SIZE N    use N entries of SZ bytes for lookaside memory
   -mmap N              default mmap size set to N
   -newline SEP         set output row separator. Default: '\n'
   -nullvalue TEXT      set text string for NULL values. Default ''
   -pagecache SIZE N    use N slots of SZ bytes each for page cache memory
   -scratch SIZE N      use N slots of SZ bytes each for scratch memory
   -separator SEP       set output column separator. Default: '|'
   -stats               print memory stats before each finalize
   -version             show SQLite version
   -vfs NAME            use NAME as the default VFS

w00343520@wuhy1w001184171 MINGW64 /d/Download/sqlite-amalgamation-3190200/sqlite-amalgamation-3190200
$
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you did or what I need to do to get it to work.

Comment: What he did was to type in everything shown after the `$` prompt.

Comment: I have compiled the sqlite on my system and test it. and attach the log for you. I hope this can help you to solve your problem.